# Print using Java a date and time from a MySql DATETIME field

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, printing

I have a problem printing a date I get from a DATETIME field from my MySQL DB. I am trying to print a field with this DATETIME information: 2013-06-23 17:29:40

The format is YEAR-MONTH-DAY HOURS:MINUTES:SECONDS.

**Priting the date I get from my DB result (cal.toString()):**
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1372001380000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Paris",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=184,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Paris,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=25,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=23,DAY_OF_YEAR=174,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=29,SECOND=40,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]

I use Integer.toString to transform int attributes to String.
However **printing the year** I get this:
1
**Printing the month:**
3
**Printing the day:**
5
**Printing the hour:**
11
**Printing the minute:**
12
**Printing the seconds:**
13

If I do this:

```
String month = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
if (month.length() == 1)
  month = "0" + month;
String day = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
if (day.length() == 1)
  day = "0" + day;
String hour = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
if (hour.length() == 1)
  hour = "0" + hour;
String minute = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
if (minute.length() == 1)
  minute = "0" + minute;
String second = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
if (second.length() == 1)
  second = "0" + second;
String date= cal.YEAR + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
```

I got this if I print the **date string**:
1-06-23 17:29:40

Does anybody know what is happening and how can I print the right date? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) and then [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you got the `Calendar` instance, you can get `Date` instance from it, and formatted string with `SimpleDateFormat`. For example,

```
Date d = cal.getTime();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
String s = df.format(d); // formatted date
```

The reason you got the wrong string is... cal.YEAR is static constance of `Calendar` class and its value is defined as `1`.

```
String date= cal.YEAR + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
             ^^^^^^^^
```

That's why you got the wrong year.

If you should get each value of year, month, date, hour, minute, second, it can be done like this:

```
String year = String.format("%d", cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String month = String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
String date = String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
String hour = String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
String minute = String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
String second = String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @ntalbs. I need year, month, day, hour, minutes and seconds in separated fields. I am exporting my DB to a custom format in a XML file and I need each field in the proper XML tag: XML file will be used to restore the server DB on a smartphone (parsing it with an app).

Comment: @Alberto That is not what you are asking in your question; if you have a specific reason to get the values separately, you need to mention that. But I think ntalbs correctly answers the problem as well. You aren't getting the year, you are simply printing out the constant `Calendar.YEAR`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, that's what I want to say. Anyway, I appended additional code to get each field.

Comment: Thank you so much @ntalbs: that really helped me. It worked fine (I just changed the hour because I need it in 24 hours format [Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel when I repplied the answer wasn't as it was when you wrote: ntalbs just wrote until fiste code section... and it was because I didn't specify all my needs about the date parsing (so it was my fault). The rest of the answer was added after my repply, when I provided all the information (the information I should have included on my question).
Thanks to both.
Answer accepted :)

Comment: @Alberto Sorry, I didn't see that as SO doesn't always show an answer (or question) as edited if it has been edited it within a few minutes by the same user.

Comment: Don't worry @MarkRotteveel. Anyway it was my fault because I didn't post the question with all the details. Thank you for helping me! :) Regards.